# Stored procedure - get anticipated columns before fully executing statement?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working through a stored procedure and wondering if there's a way to retrieve the anticipated result column list from a sql statement before fully executing.

Scenarios:

- dynamic SQL
- a UDF that might vary the columns outside of our control

EX:

```
//inbound parameter
SET QUERY_DEFINITION_ID = 12345;

//Initial statement pulls query text from bank of queries
var sqlText = getQueryFromQueryBank(QUERY_DEFINITION_ID);

//now we run our query
var cmd = {sqlText: sqlText };
stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
```

What I'd like to be able to do is say "right - before you run this, give me the anticipated column list" so I can compare it to what's expected.

EX:

- Expected: [col1, col2, col3, col4]
- Got: [col1]
- Result: Oops. Don't run.

Rationale here is that I want to short-circuit the execution if something is missing - before it potentially runs for a while. I can validate all of this after the fact, but it would be really helpful to stop early.

Any ideas very much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the use case, so if not please clarify. If you specify the columns in the select and one or more aren't there, the query will return an error quickly that you can catch in a TRY/CATCH block. If you're using SELECT * and need to test for the columns you're expecting, the easiest way would be to add the column names to the select explicitly and use TRY/CATCH. That way the query won't run long without returning the columns you're expecting.

Comment: Are you dynamically constructing the query? If you are please show this in your question. If you aren’t, then a SQL query always returns a fixed number of columns, and you must know how many columns you’ve included in your select statement, so your question doesn’t make a lot if sense, to me. Please could you clarify what you are actually doing and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Edits made for clarity per request. We're trying to replicate the equivalent of something like 'SET FMTONLY ON' so we can check to see what the anticipated structure looks like before allowing a potentially expensive query to run when it won't conform to the required result set structure. We can run it and check the result set - but then we have the question of both execution time and potential cost.

Comment: Still doesn’t make much sense, at least to me. You have a load of queries stored in your query bank, each of which will have a fixed set of columns in its select statement - and then you want to check if that list of columns is correct? Against what criteria are you checking if it is correct and if there are criteria you can check your queries against then why aren't you doing this at the point you wrote the queries (or saved your queries to the query bank), rather than when you try and execute the queries?

Comment: Okay, there's a way to get the column list for the result without running the query, but it won't tell you (at least not without untying the Gordian knot) the origin of the columns. For example, if the column is an alias and calculated, it won't be easy to tell that. If you just want a list of the number of columns and their names, I can write SP code to do that. Let me know if that would help and I can write it.

Answer (score 0):

This sample SP code shows how to get a list of columns that a query will project into the result before you run the query. It should only be used for large, long running queries because it will take a few seconds to get the column list.

There are a couple of caveats. 1) It will only return the names of the columns. It won't tell you how they were built, that is, whether they're aliased, direct from a table, calculated, etc. 2) The example query I used is straight from the Snowflake documentation here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sample-data-tpcds.html#functional-query-definition. For convenience, I minimized the query to a single line. The output of the columns includes object qualifiers in addition to the column names, so V1.I_CATEGORY, V1.D_YEAR, V1.D_MOY, etc. If you don't want them to make it easier to compare names, you can strip off the qualifiers using the JavaScript split function on the dot and take index 1 of the resulting array.

```
create or replace procedure EXPLAIN_BEFORE_RUNNING()
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
    // Set the context for the session to the TPC-H sample data:
    executeNonQuery("use schema snowflake_sample_data.tpcds_sf10tcl;");
    
    // Here's a complex query from the Snowflake docs (minimized to one line for convienience):
    var sql = `with v1 as( select i_category, i_brand, cc_name, d_year, d_moy, sum(cs_sales_price) sum_sales, avg(sum(cs_sales_price)) over(partition by i_category, i_brand, cc_name, d_year) avg_monthly_sales, rank() over (partition by i_category, i_brand, cc_name order by d_year, d_moy) rn from item, catalog_sales, date_dim, call_center where cs_item_sk = i_item_sk and cs_sold_date_sk = d_date_sk and cc_call_center_sk= cs_call_center_sk and ( d_year = 1999 or ( d_year = 1999-1 and d_moy =12) or ( d_year = 1999+1 and d_moy =1)) group by i_category, i_brand, cc_name , d_year, d_moy), v2 as( select v1.i_category ,v1.d_year, v1.d_moy ,v1.avg_monthly_sales ,v1.sum_sales, v1_lag.sum_sales psum, v1_lead.sum_sales nsum from v1, v1 v1_lag, v1 v1_lead where v1.i_category = v1_lag.i_category and v1.i_category = v1_lead.i_category and v1.i_brand = v1_lag.i_brand and v1.i_brand = v1_lead.i_brand and v1.cc_name = v1_lag.cc_name and v1.cc_name = v1_lead.cc_name and v1.rn = v1_lag.rn + 1 and v1.rn = v1_lead.rn - 1) select * from v2 where d_year = 1999 and avg_monthly_sales > 0 and case when avg_monthly_sales > 0 then abs(sum_sales - avg_monthly_sales) / avg_monthly_sales else null end > 0.1 order by sum_sales - avg_monthly_sales, 3 limit 100;`;

    // Before actually running the query, generate an explain plan.
    executeNonQuery("explain " + sql);
    
    // Now read the column list from the explain plan from the result set.
    var columnList = executeSingleValueQuery("COLUMN_LIST", `select "expressions" as COLUMN_LIST from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "operation" = 'Result';`);
    
    // For now, just exit with the column list as the output...
    return columnList;
    
    // Your code here...


    // Helper functions:

function executeNonQuery(queryString) {
    var out = '';
    cmd = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
}

function executeSingleValueQuery(columnName, queryString) {
    var out;
    cmd1 = {sqlText: queryString};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    try{
        rs = stmt.execute();
        rs.next();
        return rs.getColumnValue(columnName);
    }
    catch(err) {
        if (err.message.substring(0, 18) == "ResultSet is empty"){
            throw "ERROR: No rows returned in query.";
        } else {
            throw "ERROR: " + err.message.replace(/\n/g, " ");
        } 
    }
    return out;
}

$$;

call Explain_Before_Running();
```